# Improper parametric arc length

Tags: improper-integrals, parametric

[image: a busy cat]

The first thought I had to solve this problem was using the integral,

$$
\int_1^\infty \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}\: \:dt
$$
Once you solve for the derivatives you get this expression and do a lot of simplifying via maxima:

$$
\int_1^\infty \sqrt{\frac{1}{t^4}+ \left( \frac{2t\cos t\sin t + (1-t^2)\cos(t)^2 - 1}{t^4} \right) }  \, dt
$$

[image: a busy cat]

adding and taking the square root(sorry if my latex is bad this is my first time).

[image: a busy cat]

However one cannot integrate this so I am stuck.
I have thought about converting this to cartesian coordinate, however the graph looks radically different. The function is $x\cdot sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which instinct tell me is also not integratable. Is there any way to solve this problem please help I have not found a solution anywhere. Could converting to polar and then taking the integral help. This is from calculus eight edition. I have found out that is path length is divergent can you prove that?

Comment: I've added MathJax for the expression in one of your images.  For now your image is still there.  It is incorrect to include $dt$ within the radical: it needs to be outside the radical, saying $\int \sqrt{\cdots\cdots}\,dt$ and _not_ $\int \sqrt{\cdots\cdots\,dt}$.  By $\cos(t)^2$ I don't know whether you mean $(\cos t)^2$ or $\cos(t^2)$, either of which, unlike your notation, is unambiguous.

Comment: I am so grateful for your help.Btw I mean (cos t)^2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following sequence of $t$-values:
$$t = \frac{\pi}{2} , \,\,\,\, 3 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}, \,\,\,\, 5 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}, \,\,\,\, 7 \frac{\pi}{2},\,\,\,\, \ldots
$$
The corresponding $y$-values are
$$y = \frac{2}{\pi}, \,\,\,\, - \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{\pi}, \,\,\,\, \frac{1}{5} \frac{2}{\pi}, \,\,\,\, - \frac{1}{7} \frac{2}{\pi}, \,\,\,\,\ldots
$$
So as your graph zig-zags up and down from one of these $y$-values to the next, its length must be no less than than $2/\pi$ times
$$1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \cdots = +\infty
$$

Comment: Can you use any arbitary divergent sequence? If the integral actually converged would there be a finite sequence? What is this technique called?

Comment: @Sumo: If this technique has a name, it's simply "analysis", and if you asked me what "analysis" was, I would just say it is the art of estimating. That's what this example is: finding a good lower estimate, one which diverges, allowing you to conclude that the given integral diverges.

Comment: @Sumo: if the integral converged, then yes, if you picked any sequence $t_1 < t_2 < t_3 < …$, and if you computed the corresponding points $(x_1,y_2), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3), …$ then the sum of distances from each point to the next would converge. That's just an application of the triangle inequality.